# backup Android, Windows 7, Windows 8.1 and Ubuntuu Folders to the same server

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-8.1, ubuntu-14.04, android-backup-service

i know this question is not typical for stackoverflow, but maybe some of you are willing to help me managing my backup strategy. i want to upload certain folders from my android device, windows 8.1 tablet, windows 7 notebook and ubuntu on my workplace. the best strategy for me would be the following as i figured out:

android folders should be backed up with the condition:
2 hours after i plugged the phone in for charging

same condition for my windows 8.1 tablet:
backup the folder 2 hours after i plugged in for charging

my windows 7 notebook should backup:
every time after restart

same condition for ubuntu:
backup every time after restart

i appreciate every idea that brings me further to mange this, especially for apps that could help me on windows and ubuntuu. google didnt help me a lot yet.
Best regards and sry for my bad german english

Answer (score 0):

Alright, since no one has answered, it's actually pretty easy. I've literally just done this with my sisters Windows Phone 8.1 (Nokia Lumia 909) - use MicroUSB cable, make sure the phone is unlocked (i.e. you can see the "Live Tiles") and Ubuntu should mount it automagically. It'll show "Phone" as a drive, go into that and you'll see the following folders: Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures, Ringtones, and Videos.